# python dictionary/json inception

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary

How do you pull, split, and append an array inside a dictionary inside a dictionary?

This is the data I've got:

```
data = {
    "Event":{
        "distribution":"0",
        "orgc":"Oxygen",
        "Attribute": [{
            "type":"ip-dst",
            "category":"Network activity",
            "to_ids":"true",
            "distribution":"3",
            "value":["1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2"]
        }, {
            "type":"url",
            "category":"Network activity",
            "to_ids":"true",
            "distribution":"3",
            "value":["msn.com","google.com"]
        }]
    }
}
```

This is what I need --

```
{
    "Event": {
        "distribution": "0",
        "orgc": "Oxygen",
        "Attribute": [{
                "type": "ip-dst",
                "category": "Network activity",
                "to_ids": "true",
                "distribution": "3",
                "value": "1.1.1.1"
            }, {
                "type": "ip-dst",
                "category": "Network activity",
                "to_ids": "true",
                "distribution": "3",
                "value": "2.2.2.2"
            }, {
                "type": "url",
                "category": "Network activity",
                "to_ids": "true",
                "distribution": "3",
                "value": "msn.com"
            }, {
                "type": "url",
                "category": "Network activity",
                "to_ids": "true",
                "distribution": "3",
                "value": "google.com"
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is where I was just playing around with it and totally lost!!

```
for item in data["Event"]["Attribute"]:
    if "type":"ip-dst" and len("value")>1:
        if 'ip-dst' in item["type"] and len(item["value"])>1:
            for item in item["value"]:
```

...and totally lost

Comment: Aside from the tabs, what's the difference?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. The "got" and "need" look like the same structure. Are you trying to convert a dict to json?

Comment: @MadWombat The OP is trying to go from combined `"attribute"` values to individual ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
#get reference to attribute dict
attributes = data["Event"]["Attribute"]
#in the event dictionary, replace it with an empty list
data["Event"]["Attribute"] = []

for attribute in attributes:
    for value in attribute["value"]:
        #for every value in every attribute, copy that attribute
        new_attr = attribute.copy()
        #set the value to that value
        new_attr["value"] = value
        #and append it to the attribute list
        data["Event"]["Attribute"].append(new_attr)
```

This will work with the data structure you've shown, but not necessarily with all kinds of nested data, since we do a shallow copy of the attribute. That will mean that you have to make sure that apart from the `"value"` list, it only contains atomic values like numbers, strings, or booleans. The values list may contain nested structures, since we're only moving references there.